# Passing a generic type to a function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider example:

```
interface A {
   foo: string;
}

interface B {
   foo: string;
}

function a<T>() {
   function b(arg: T) {
      return arg.foo;
            ^^^^^^ Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'T'.
   }

   return b;
}

a<A>();
a<B>();
```

How to make it work so I dont have to hardcore the type like:

```
function b(arg: A | B)
```

So I will be able to pass the type as a generic so if there's like 5 or even more different types I will not have to do it like `A | B | C | D | E...` but just as a generic?

Comment: what will change if you use function a<T extends A>() { and use A as A base class.

Comment: @DraganS cant since the `A` or `B` interfaces may have a lot of different (or even conflicting) fields

Comment: Will [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nn47BW) work for your needs?  You need to tell the compiler that `T` will have a `foo` property.  If that approach works for you I can write up an answer; otherwise please [edit] the example code to demonstrate failed use cases.

Comment: As it shown currently, there's no point to use generics at all and it could be just `function b(arg: { foo: string }) { ... }`. More realistic example would help

Comment: @jcalz Yes I thought about something similar, you can make an answer I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to be able to access `arg.foo`, the compiler must be convinced that, at the bare minimum, `arg` might actually have a property named `foo`.  So the type of `arg` must be assignable to something like `{foo?: unknown}`, where `foo` is an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) and the type of the property is [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).

It's not clear from your example if you want to make something stricter than this (say that it *definitely* has a property named `foo`, or that the value at that property must be a `string`). For now, I'm only going to assume that you want to access `arg.foo` without an error.

If you are using the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` as the type of `arg`, then `T` must be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to something assignable to `{foo?: unknown}`.

For example:

```
function a<T extends { foo?: unknown }>() {
    function b(arg: T) {
        return arg.foo; // okay, no error
    }    
    return b;
}
```

This saves you from having to write `T extends A | B | C | ...`, assuming that all of the `A`, `B`, `C`, etc... types are themselves assignable to `{ foo?: unknown }`.  Your given `A` and `B` types are assignable, so the following works:

```
a<A>();
a<B>();
```

---

Do note that your `A` and `B` types from the example are actually *identical*.  TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system).  Because types `A` and `B` have the same *structure*, they are the same *type*.  It doesn't matter that there are two declarations and two different names:

```
let aVal: A = { foo: "a" };
let bVal: B = { foo: "b" };
aVal = bVal; // okay
bVal = aVal; // okay
```

So writing `T extends A` would be fine if you want the compiler to enforce that `foo` exists and is a `string`; it wouldn't stop `B` from working. A structural type system frees you from having to anticipate all possible named types:

```
function a2<T extends A>() {
    function b(arg: T) {
        return arg.foo.toUpperCase();
    }
    return b;
}
    
a2<A>(); // okay
a2<B>(); // okay

interface C {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}
a2<C>(); // okay

a2<Date>(); // error
// ~~~~
// Property 'foo' is missing in type 'Date' but required in type 'A'.
```

If you care about "hardcoding" the name `A`, you can use an anonymous type like `{foo: string}` as in `T extends {foo: string}`,  but that doesn't really change much from the type system's perspective, since `A` and `{foo: string}` are the same type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+TAewIC5kBnMKUAcwG4sBfLLUSWRFAIUxz0JPKUa9JlhgBXEAjDACIZHAA8AFWQQAHpBAATMpnxEA-KUkBrEAQDu8hgD4AFAEoeefJOmz5AI3two1UmVnbFdXKAgwcSh5P2oAOn56V1EwiKjvEWYsJVQHR3olTjz6ZgkpGTkFACYVNU0IHT1cpxc+dwrvX39A4N5Q5HDI6IV-BKI4sAIAVQAHGegAYTgyCCckvCZUoYzGLLga5vzkAHpj5AJTOABPbJqitZOzi+uWcGh4JGQF1tx+UgoqCA6H1kF4-KQQOIALZeaCZfaKBbFR7nS43W6KAAicEgyNOaigUAIUCw+IAfhSyaSzgAFInzKBgK7IADk-BZyGAeihXLINE58iZ81Z2MgHK84jAAwgAEdxMBwtoBcghSgWagWXEslgADYRBQANTgOtI6AAvPo-sgAERwa3IBj0PVSrxGk3IbgWjAGATWrz2x3ZN3IC2u420FHPG5hnUhw3hyNorBAA)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
interface A {
   foo: string;
}

interface B extends A {
   
}

function a<T extends A>() {
   function b(arg: T) {
      return arg.foo;
           
   }

   return b;
}

a<A>();
a<B>();
```

Comment: Thanks but still this is hardcoding